# Executing functions synchronously in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to execute functions synchronously one after the another

```
   function test1(){
      setTimeout(function(){console.log("should print 1st");},1000);

   }
   function test(){
     test1();
     console.log("should print 2nd");
   }
     function aftertest(){
     var dfd = $.Deferred();

         dfd.done(test()).done(tester());
         //dfd.done(test,tester);   

         //$.when(test()).then(tester());

       console.log("should print 4th");
   }
    function tester(){
       console.log("should print 3rd");
    }
    aftertest();
```

Here is [BIN](http://jsbin.com/wocojez/edit?html,console) of what I have tried so far.

Comment: remove setTimeout and change it to function test1(){
      console.log("should print 1st");
     
   }

Comment: please explain better what you need. 
You mix synchronous and asynchronous here. 
Either you want one or the other,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use .then :

```
function test1(){
      var defer = $.Deferred();
      setTimeout(function(){console.log("should print 1st");defer.resolve();},1000);
     return defer;
   }
   function test(){
     var defer = $.Deferred();
     test1().then(function() {
       console.log("should print 2nd");
       defer.resolve();
     });
     return defer;
   }
     function aftertest(){
     var dfd = $.Deferred();

         test().then(tester).then(function () {
           console.log("should print 4th");    
         });
         //dfd.done(test,tester);   

         //$.when(test()).then(tester());


   }
    function tester(){
       console.log("should print 3rd");
      return $.when();
    }
    aftertest();
```